# Google Translate: UI translates but API fails

Tags: google-translate, google-cloud-translate

Just struggling with the following thing:

I have a lot of kind-of-comments-dirty-writing-manner comments. Comments came from India region, and there is a mix of languages (but not within the single comment). In addition there are samples with the transliteration, and I was wondering whether I can detect the language in this kind of mess.

But with Google Translate UI I found it deals with it.

[image: Example of Google Translate UI dealing with transliteration]

As may be seen Google Translate UI detects language (probably correctly), suggests how the text should be written in the language detected, and finally translated it.

In contrast, Google Translate API does not give such a translation, but detects the language yet. Here's the response for the same input string:

```
translations {
  translated_text: "Theek kiya"
  detected_language_code: "hi"
}
```

So, I just wondering whether UI does additional stuff before it runs the translation, like spelling or whatever.

I do not see what did I missed with the API to *make it* finally translate the text.

Maybe someone faced the same problem and can help me?

Comment: Currently, Cloud translate API doesn’t support translation for Hindi written in the Latin alphabet. Thus, when translating "ठीक किया" into English, "Did the right thing" is sent back. Conversely, translating "Did the right thing" from English to Hindi is translated into "सही काम किया", but translating "Theek kiya" does not work as it is not written in the Hindi alphabet.

Comment: The same has been raised as an issue in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/189744674) that will be updated whenever there is progress. However, we cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: Just wondering how Google Translate UI dealt with latin Hindi and Telugu. It might be some additional layer which "translates" latin Hindi/Telugu into native alphabet, which can be handled by Google Translate. May be there should be some additional Google service exploited, but don't know which. And cannot find the answer in the Google.